# Birth date dropdown (Yii)

Tags: php, yii

I have a page, where user can edit his own info. On this page there are also 3 dropdown lists for birth date (date, month, year). But I have only one column for birth date in my table, which accepts value in format "ddmmyyyy"
How can I render these 3 fields in CActiveForm, so they together fill one complete value, like "ddmmyyyy"?
Thank you. 
**Update:**
Model code:

```
public $day;
public $month;
public $year;

public function getDates()
{
     return array(
       20=>20,
       21=>21,
    );
}
public function getMonth()
{
     return array(
       01=>01,
       02=>02,
    );
}
public function getYears()
{
     return array(
       1990=>1990,
       1991=>1991,
    );
}
```

Controller code:

```
if(isset($_POST['User']))
            {
                $user->attributes=$_POST['User'];
                $user->day = $_POST['User']['day'];
                $user->month = $_POST['User']['month'];
                $user->year = $_POST['User']['year'];
                $date = $user->day . $user->month . $user->year;
                $user->birthday = $date;
                if($user->save())
                    $this->redirect('/user/index');
            }
```

View code:

```
                <div class="day">
                    <?php echo $form->dropDownList($user,'day', $user->getDates()); ?>
                </div>
                <div class="month">
                    <?php echo $form->dropDownList($user,'month', $user->getMonth()); ?>
                </div>
                <div class="year">
                    <?php echo $form->dropDownList($user,'year', $user->getYears()); ?>
                </div>
```

Comment: why dont you try a single field and `CJuiDatePicker` (http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CJuiDatePicker)

Comment: It's not suitable for my situation :)

Comment: Just as user: I hate dropdowns to show date, just allow me to print date to one field in any format

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your model class create these 3 properties by hand. On your form you will reference just these three properties. You will make use of the events to wrap your database column values to these three fields like this:

In `afterFind()`, make sure you have code that will split the database column property in all these three.

In `beforeValidate()` make sure you have code that will take these three properties and join together in the database column property.

Add the necessary validation to the `rules()` and labels to `attributes()`.

**Update**

First of all some changes

```
$user->attributes=$_POST['User'];
$user->day = $_POST['User']['day'];
$user->month = $_POST['User']['month'];
$user->year = $_POST['User']['year'];
```

you don't need all the assignments if you add the day, month, year attribute to the 'safe' list. Read more at [Understanding safe validation rules](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/161/understanding-safe-validation-rules/).

Move this code to the model class:

```
protected function beforeValidate()
{
   $this->birthday = $this->day . $this->month . $this->year;
   return parent::beforeValidate();
}
```

Make sure you call validation to validate the form:

```
if($user->validate() && $user->save())
         $this->redirect('/user/index');
```

add code to afterFind() that is reverse to beforeValidate() as

```
protected function afterFind()
{
    $this->day= ...get day part from $this->birthday...
    $this->month=
    $this->year=
    return parent::afterFind();
}
```

You don't need all those getMonth() functions. You can use the [range](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) or the [array_fill](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php) functions from PHP.

Comment: Thanks, I've created 3 properties, but I didn't followed your instructions as for the `afterFind()` and `beforeValidation()`.
I've created 3 variables in a controller that are taking the value from `$_POST` as Md. Mahabubur Rahman advised.
Everything works perfect, but how can I show user what date he chose?

Comment: You are using a model right? These events are defined in the model, and you can implement code to make use of these events. If you are creating the properties in the controller and use individual $_POST then you loose validation. You need to show us the entire code you have for model/controller/action/view/form

Comment: Thank you very much. I've understood everything, except "add code to afterFind() that is reverse to beforeValidate() as instructed". Can you please explain?

Comment: Thank you, I have one more question. If I use `range()`, how can I specify that the values must start with zero (e.g. 01,02)?

Comment: you need to use str_pad to adjust the value after.

Answer (score 2):

That means you get three variable value

you have to declare three variable.

```
 $date=$_REQUEST['date'];
 $month=$_REQUEST['month'];
 $year=$_REQUEST['year'];
```

and you have other variable.

```
 $birth_date=$date."/".$month."/".$year;
```

And then you will send this     **$birth_date** variable data to your database table fild